# What is use of -D in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

`-Dspring` where property file can read with like `-Dspring.tenantid` and `-Dtenantid`

Comment: `-D` defines a _system property_. This is not specific to Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `-D` is one of java command options and Sets a system property value.

`java -Dmydir="some string" SomeClass`

Reference here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

> In sprinboot applications we use this to set properties in environment.

If the same property exist in properties files then property passed through `-D` will take precedence.

Reference - https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Answer (score 2):

The `-D` is not a Spring thing. It is a Java command-line thing.
`-D` is used to pass System Property key and value.

You can either choose to pass it over the command line or read from a property file and set it to System properties.

Spring uses System properties with a configurable prefix to ease configuration of connection parameters like Database or JMS.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

`-D` is a marker sort of, any variable you want to declare/overwrite

Any key-value you want to declare will start with this.